# JS - Convert an Array or a String to arguments list [SQLite insert with bind parameters]

Tags: javascript, sqlite, data-binding, arguments

There is any way to convert an Array or a String to an arguments list for a function?

```
var data = ['ricardo','portugal',23];

test(data);
```

Instead of passing the test array to the example function, the pretended result is:

```
test('ricardo','portugal',23);
```

This is my issue: I'm trying to create a SQLite insert function in JavaScript, according to the [Appcelerator Documentation](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Working+with+a+SQLite+Database#WorkingwithaSQLiteDatabase-Storingdata)

This is my insert function:

```
var insert = function(rows) {

    if(rows.length) {

        var columns = "";

        _.each(rows[0],function(value) {

            columns += value + ",";
        });

        var query = "INSERT INTO users (" + columns + ") VALUES (?,?,?)";//"INSERT INTO users (name,country,age) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        columns = columns.slice(0, -1);

        _.map(rows,function(row) {

            var data1 = []
                data2 = "";

            _.each(row,function(value) {

                data1.push(value);
                data2 += value + ",";
            });

            data2 = data2.slice(0, -1);

            db.execute(query,data1); //test 1 - 'INSERT INTO users (name,country,age) VALUES (?,?,?)',['Ricardo','Portugal','24']
            db.execute(query,data2); //test 2 - 'INSERT INTO users (name,country,age) VALUES (?,?,?)',"'Ricardo','Portugal','24'"
            //expected result: 'INSERT INTO users (name,country,age) VALUES (?,?,?)','Ricardo','Portugal','24'
        });
    }
};
```

This is a running example:

```
insert([
    {name:"Ricardo",country:"Portugal",age:24},
    {name:"John",country:"England",age:27}
]);
```

Comment: Why not `test(data[0],data[1],data[2]);` or map it to the object `{name:data[0],country:data[1],age:data[2]}`? Could you provide some context on that?

Comment: I'm getting the data that I've passed to the insert function as a result of an http call, the result can have any number of properties, for example, the translations data have 4 columns, the users data have 23 columns, but if I change the query (server side) that returns that data, I could add or remove columns

Comment: Then if you have a variable input size why do you want to convert the array to multiple argument, since your function will also need to consider that it can have 1 argument or 20 and I'm sure your `test` function isn't going to be `function test(arg1, ... , arg20)`. Sorry if I'm not understanding the problem

Comment: thanks for your time, after some research trough the documentation I've found that there is no need to separate the values to insert, it accepts the values as an array

Answer (score 1):

After some research trough the documentation I've found that there is no need to separate the values to insert, it accepts the values as an array:

```
var thisName = 'Arthur';
var thisPhoneNo = '1-617-000-0000';
var thisCity = 'Mountain View';
db.execute('INSERT INTO people (name, phone_number, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', thisName, thisPhoneNo, thisCity);
```

What I need:

```
var personArray = ['Paul','020 7000 0000', 'London'];
db.execute('INSERT INTO people (name, phone_number, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', personArray);
```

[Appcelerator Documentation: Ti.Database.ResultSet](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database.ResultSet)